# difference jasmine beforeeach vs variable equal to value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

can anybody tell me the difference of following Jasmine codes, pardon me if it is silly

```
describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
    var $scope;

    beforeEach(function(){
        $scope = 'Hello World'
    });

    it('should say hello to the World', function() {
        expect($scope).toEqual('Hello World');
    });
});
```

AND

```
describe('Testing a Hello World controller', function() {
    var $scope = 'Hello World';

    it('should say hello to the World', function() {
        expect($scope).toEqual('Hello World');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None because you have just one test in each describe, try with this:

```
describe('beforeEach example', function() {
        var $scope = 0;

        beforeEach(function(){
            $scope += 1
        });

        it('should be 1', function() {
            expect($scope).toEqual(1);
        });

        it('should be 2', function() {
            expect($scope).toEqual(2);
        });
    });
```